# Associate a swt List with layout that contain two different styles

Tags: java, swt

I have a swt List:

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List list = new List(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

I would like to have a style (non bold font) associated with the first 3 characters of each item in the list and another style (bold font) associated with the following 3 characters of each item in the list.

I think I can use a layout like this:

```
final TextLayout textLayout = new TextLayout(shell.getDisplay());  
list.setLayoutData(textLayout);
TextStyle nonBoldStyle = new TextStyle(getNonBoldFont(), null, null);
TextStyle boldStyle = new   TextStyle(getBoldFont(), null, null);
textLayout.setStyle(nonBoldStyle, 0, 2);
textLayout.setStyle(boldStyle, 3, 5);
```

How can I associate the layout with the list? I can not find a way to do it.

Comment: TextLayout can't be used in setLayoutData. `List` doesn't support different fonts for characters. If you can use JFace then a TableViewer with a StyledCellLabelProvider is probably the easiest.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use JFace. I must use SWT. Maybe I can use a different structure than List, but from SWT. This list in my code is used to show a dropdown menu.

Comment: For just SWT you can use Table with custom draw - see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html)

Comment: It looks interesting. I will try to do it with Table and a custom draw. Thank you.